# Filter on secondary date outside of timeline

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with operation dates and ship dates (and other data, but these are the relevant fields for the functionality)

| Index | Operation Date | Ship Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2019 | 1/5/2019 |
| 2 | 1/2/2019 | 1/5/2019 |
| 3 | 1/3/2019 | 2/2/2019 |
| 4 | 1/3/2019 | 2/5/2019 |

I have a slicer that chooses the month for Operation Date to display in the report. I would like to be able to add a slicer for "In-Period" and "Out-of-Period" ship dates.

With "January 2019" selected on the slicer for Operation Date, if "In-Period" is selected then rows 1 and 2 would be returned. If "Out-of-Period" were selected then rows 3 and 4 would be returned.

I have previously done this using a fixed period for the Operation Date selection and a calculated column for the "In/Out of Period" field. This requires a refresh if we change the time period for Operation Date and that is to be avoided.

I have also done this using a second slicer, but that takes up extra real-estate on the form and extra clicks when they both serve to select the same date range.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.